# Update specific value in array mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update my hairdresser schema, and more precisely one object of my services array.

```js
const hairdresserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  label: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  stripe: { type: String, required: false },
  phone: { type: String, required: true },
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  services: [
    {
      _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
      label: { type: String },
      service: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "category" }],
      price: { type: Number },
      supplement: { type: Number },
      duration: { type: Number }
    }
  ]
});

const workerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  label: { type: String, required: true },
  entity: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "hairdresser" },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  availability: [
    {
      id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false },
      date: { type: Date, required: false },
      stops: [
        {
          stop: { type: String },
          booked: { type: Boolean }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  required: false
});
```

I tried to use $set and $ notation in order to target the desired object but Mongo keeps telling me that it's impossible to create a property.

```
 worker.update(
        {
            'availability.stops._id': req.body.basicID
        },

        {
            $set: {
                'availability.stops.$.booked': true,
            }
        }
    )
```

Here is a JSON formatted example of my worker schema :

```
{ _id: 5e4d6adbb12e8b5ccbb87d94,
  label: 'Germain',
  entity: 5e3d39fb0b40f96f98d33c1a,
  description: 'Je prendrai soin de vos cheveux',
  availability:
   [ { stops: [{ _id: 5e4d6adbsdfds2e8b5ccbb87d75, stop: "10:00", booked: false }, { _id: 5e4d6adbsdfds2sdfd8b5ccbb87d75, stop: "10:15", booked: false }],
       _id: 5e5edfd15605520adb7af977,
       date: 2020-03-03T23:00:00.000Z },
     { stops: [{ _id: 5e4d6adbb12e8b5ccbb87d92, stop: "08:00", booked: false }, { _id: 5e4d6adbb12e8b5ccbb87d75, stop: "08:15", booked: false }],
       _id: 5e5edfe05605520adb7af988,
       date: 2020-03-03T23:00:00.000Z } ],
  __v: 0 } ]
}
```

I need to upd
Any idea how to make it work ?

Comment: Please add worker schema instead of hairdresser schema.

Comment: My bad @NicolaeMaties.

Comment: Actually it is good to see both off the schemas, so I added it to the question.

Comment: Can you please add sample documents for both in json format?

Comment: Done ! I need to update (for example), one of stops' element (I've got its ID), and set its property to true. @SuleymanSah

Comment: Please make it clear whether you want to update hairdresserSchema services array, workerSchema  availability stops array? In the first sentence you wrote: `I'm trying to update my hairdresser schema, and more precisely one object of my services array.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [filtered positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to update nested arrays.

```js
router.put("/workers/:workerId/:stopId", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Worker.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.workerId,
    {
      $set: {
        "availability.0.stops.$[stopId].booked": true
      }
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [{ "stopId._id": req.params.stopId }],
      new: true
    }
  );
  res.send(result);
});
```

Let's say we have this document:

```
{
    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3be7",
    "label": "Germain",
    "entity": "5e3d39fb0b40f96f98d33c1a",
    "description": "Je prendrai soin de vos cheveux",
    "availability": [
        {
            "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3beb",
            "stops": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3bed",
                    "stop": "10:00",
                    "booked": false
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3bec",
                    "stop": "10:15",
                    "booked": false
                }
            ],
            "date": "2020-03-03T23:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3be8",
            "stops": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3bea",
                    "stop": "08:00",
                    "booked": false
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3be9",
                    "stop": "08:15",
                    "booked": false
                }
            ],
            "date": "2020-03-03T23:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

If we want to update the stop with _id `5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3bec` for this document with `_id: "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3be7"`, we send a PUT request `http://.../workers/5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3be7/5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3bec`

The result will be:

```
{
    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3be7",
    "label": "Germain",
    "entity": "5e3d39fb0b40f96f98d33c1a",
    "description": "Je prendrai soin de vos cheveux",
    "availability": [
        {
            "stops": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3bed",
                    "stop": "10:00",
                    "booked": false
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3bec",
                    "stop": "10:15",
                    "booked": true   => UPDATED
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3beb",
            "date": "2020-03-03T23:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "stops": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3bea",
                    "stop": "08:00",
                    "booked": false
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3be9",
                    "stop": "08:15",
                    "booked": false
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5e5f8a2bf9f62d7558ad3be8",
            "date": "2020-03-03T23:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver, I wasn't aware of using $ marker with an index... that's what I was looking for ! Thanks !!

Comment: Just a question, here, we target availability[0] but I've got multiple objects inside.. How can I manage to get an universal function checking in all my availability object [0], [1], [2]..... to update the target ?

Comment: @GermainPerdigal can you try $[] ? [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with)